# Could not find any application or handler for sslauncher:///?ssurl=url Chrome Fedora SSLauncher

Tags: google-chrome, fedora, putty, xdgutils

I am on fedora and i have `putty` installed. I logged on to a site where different credentials for different servers are stored. If I go into one of the server information it shows an Icon saying `PuttyLauncher` if I click on it, an alert opens asking me to open with `xdg-open`. After clicking on it i get the error

`Could not find any application or handler for sslauncher:///?ssurl=url...`

`xdg-open` do not know what to do. If i am on windows the process completes successfully ending up opening putty session. Some how i have to tell chrome that here is my installation of the putty on fedora to open and I don't know how. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"There is no support for ClickOnce technology on non-Windows platforms at this time"

From https://thycotic.force.com/support/s/article/Using-Launcher-from-your-web-browser